# In JavaFX, how to open another stage without losing focus of the first one?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a main stage that must open another stage without losing focus of the first one. I know i can call `mainWindow.requestFocus()` after calling `secondWindow.show()` but i want to make it to work without the first window even losing focus.

I wanto to do this because the second stage is a notification window with StageStyle.TRANSPARENT, that stays always on top and closes itself after some seconds.
Is there a way to make the second window "unfocusable"?

Comment: A [Popup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html) or [PopupControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html) might work, though technically they're Windows, not Stages.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to create a new `Stage` for showing your notification window? You could also use `javafx.stage.Popup` which creates transparent windows by default (so you would not need to set `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`). Another advantage of using `Popup` instead of `Stage` is that it doesn't "steal" the focus from your main stage, wich should be pretty much what you need.

Here is some more information about the popup class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html

And here is a simple example of how to use a popup in your application: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1926196

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to do this embedding my java fx stage inside a swing JFrame. On JFrame i can do what i want. here is how:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(fxPanel);
frame.setSize(422, 116);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
fxPanel.setScene(scene);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setFocusableWindowState(false); // <- Here is the secret
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If anyone knows a less dirty way of doing this, i would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You need some parameters for this. There is a method called `stage.setOnShown()` that will be called immediatly after opening the new stage.

But be aware of the code down below, it will open the second stage without any possibility to close it, so you need to kill the app. This could be made better with a timer where the windows automatically will close.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class TwoStage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Open second stage");
        btn.setOnAction((e) -> {
            Label l = new Label("I'm a second window");
            Scene s = new Scene(l, 100, 100);
            Stage s1 = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            s1.centerOnScreen();
            s1.setScene(s);
            s1.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            s1.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            s1.setOnShown((e1) -> {
                primaryStage.requestFocus();
            });
            s1.show();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Two Windows");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the first to window to loose focus, then gain focus again when the second window is shown?

Comment: Maybe yes, but this is a so short time that a user won't recognize it.

Comment: That's the problem, in my case it can't happen, because that could compromise data integrity.

Comment: And what about the Popup? Couldn't be that a solution?

Comment: A popup would work but not in my case, cause it needs a parent stage, which i don't have (the code which would call the popup can be called from places where i don't have a Stage opened)